# Use apex:relatedlist in visual force component

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, related-list

This is my VF page "TestPage":

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<c:TestComponent recordId="{!account}" />
</apex:page>
```

Visual Force component "Test Component":

```
<apex:component controller="Taccount">
<apex:attribute name="recordId" description="Record Id to show field history for." type="sobject"  assignTo="{!record}" required="true"/>
 <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities"/> 
<apex:relatedList list="record.Opportunities"/> 
</apex:component>
```

Problem is that  `<apex:relatedList list="Opportunities"/> or   <apex:relatedList list="record.Opportunities"/>`  is not showed in the main page"TestPage".

Do you know how can i show, in the main page, a related list added in a component?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are you passing some accountid to the Testpage, is your url looking like https://c.na.visual.force.com/apex/testpage?Id=oo1ABCDE90000

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/prbrKKEv2H may be this link can help you

Comment: @Rao Yes , I´m passing it :/apex/test_page?id=001w000001AiKCe. No luck

Comment: Any luck on this? Am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting the `subject` attribute of [`apex:relatedList`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm).

For example:

The component can be written to accept the account record as an attribute passed into it.

```
<apex:component>
  <apex:attribute name="acctRec" type="Account" description="The Account passed in"/>
  <apex:relatedList subject="{!acctRec}" list="Opportunities"/>
</apex:component>
```

The VF Page can pass the account record.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <c:testComponent acctRec="{!account}" />
</apex:page>
```

The result will be that the Opportunities for the Account specified by the id parameter will be displayed within the component.
[image: Opportunities related list]

Comment: Much better to only accept the Id. Only pass what you need!